# Creating XML from a for-loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop

Hi I'm trying to create a XML from an for-loop. But with this below code I only get the Last element found on the page. Not all of them as I expected.

Consider that there are many elements on the page with id's like "textHolder1, textHolder2 etc. With all different content.

Jquery:

```
var text = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><canvas>";

text += "<elements>";   
text_length =  $('[id^="textHolder"]').length;  
for(var n = 0; n < text_length; n++){
TextElementID = $('[id^="textHolder"]').attr('id');
TextElementContent = $('[id^="textHolder"]').text();  
text += "<element id='"+TextElementID+"'>";  
text += "<content>"+TextElementContent;  
text += "</content>";  
text += "</element>";  
}
text += "</elements>";         
text +="</canvas>";

alert(text)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Inside the for loop you are doing `$('[id^="textHolder"]')` on each iteration, which selects ALL elements that match the selector. You are then getting the id of the first matched element and the content of the first matched element. That obviously isn't what you want.

Comment: Consider using [`eq` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this, using each loop:

```
var text = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><canvas>";

text += "<elements>";
$('[id^="textHolder"]').each(function(){
    var TextElementID = this.id,
        TextElementContent = $(this).text();
    text += "<element id='" + TextElementID + "'>";
    text += "<content>" + TextElementContent;
    text += "</content>";
    text += "</element>";
});
text += "</elements>";
text += "</canvas>";

alert(text)
```

Comment: Well, that is what I call a perfect answer! Thanks! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues. I dont see where you're declaring some variables, also, you're selecting a group of elements and trying to get an ID. I believe this code clears it up (not tested);

```
var text = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><canvas>";

text += "<elements>";   
var text_length =  $('[id^="textHolder"]').length;  

for(var n = 0; n < text_length; n++){
    var TextElementID = $('[id="textHolder' + i + '"]').attr('id');
    var TextElementContent = $('[id="textHolder' + i + '"]').text();  
    text += "<element id='"+TextElementID+"'>";  
    text += "<content>"+TextElementContent;  
    text += "</content>";  
    text += "</element>";  
}
text += "</elements>";         
text +="</canvas>";

alert(text)
```